# Sending rich text email from Outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the following (piece of) code in a macro to send outlook emails using Excel VBA.

```
Function send_mail_rich_text(ByVal send_to As String, ByVal mail_subject As String, ByVal mail_content As Range, ByVal cc_list As String, ByVal bcc_list As String, ByVal rr As String) As String

Set psht = ActiveSheet

Err.Number = 0

If LCase(rr) = "yes" Then
    rr_boo = True
Else
    rr_boo = False
End If

Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

olMailItem = 0
Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'get Excel cell range which shall be in the mail
Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set oWS = Range("mail.content").Worksheet
oWS.Activate
Set oRange = mail_content

oRange.Copy ' Range is now in Clipboard

On Error Resume Next

Dim oWdDoc As Object

With oOlMItem
    '.Display
    .To = send_to
    .CC = cc_list
    .BCC = bcc_list
    .Subject = mail_subject
    .ReadReceiptRequested = rr_boo

    Set oOlInsp = .GetInspector
    Set oWdDoc = oOlInsp.WordEditor ' get Word Document from the MailBody
    olFormatRichText = 3
    .bodyformat = olFormatRichText ' change to RichTextFormat

    Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range        
    oWdRng.Paste ' paste Excel range from Clipboard

    Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range

    .send

End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    save_mail_rich_text = "error"
Else
    save_mail_rich_text = "sent"
End If

psht.Activate

End Function
```

However, I get can a compile error on the line "`Set oWdDoc = oOlInsp.WordEditor`". Error says "`Function call on the left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object`". Further, the strange part is that I have two macros with the exact same code except that one sends and the other saves draft. The compilation error occurs only in case of send macro. What I am missing here?

Comment: How have you declared `oWdDoc` ?

Comment: I had not but I just tried again with declaration (as object) and it still doesn't work. Also, it works fine without declaration in the other macro (same macro, same module, same file, just saves instead of send). Do you want me to the share the full code?

Comment: Yes, please share full code, the `.` prefix means its enclosed in a `with` statement, but don't know what etc..

Comment: The `.send` or `.display` covers the difference, however you need to allow programatic access to OUtlook, something may be done on one machine, but not the other.

Comment: Added full code now. It is the same machine, Excel file, module, macro calling this function, everything is exactlyt the same except the last line where it is save instead of send.

Comment: interesting. i've never seen it done this way. i typically use `RangeToHTML` function and `.htmlbody` with the mail message. maybe consider that as an alternative approach

Comment: Also, have you added the Word Object Reference Library?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I had that approach before and works well except that it results in a table inside email with a visible gap on the top of body. My client is too finicky about it so had to switch to rich text editing.

Comment: @dsauce - that spacing gap can be controlled for sure. you just have to fiddle with the html

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I had not but I tried now after adding it and still the same error. As I said before, the other equivalent function works fine with same reference scenario.

Comment: Do you run it with the on error statement in, turn that off if so, it could be an error from a previous line?  The only difference between the 2 macros is saving or sending?  THey are in the same workbook and on the same machine?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman trust me, I tried a lot of fiddling with the html code that comes out from rangeToHTML and couldn't eliminate that space. It came in from Outlook after setting the HTML code to provide external padding to the table. Had to resort to rich text.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have tried with & without on error statment. Also, the compile error is on the entire function, doesn't point to a line. I played with each line to conclude it is that line which is causing the issue. Yes, the only difference is saving & sending. Same workbook, same machine.

Comment: How are you using this?  You're returning a string from the function, but you are not setting `send_mail_rich_text` you are setting `save_mail_rich_text`

Comment: Also, why are you resetting standard enumartions, like `olFormatRichText = 3` ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Perfect. I was hoping it must be a stupid error. I missed correcting this when copy-pasting the macro from save to send. Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Function send_mail_rich_text(ByVal send_to As String, ByVal mail_subject As String, _
    ByVal mail_content As Range, ByVal cc_list As String, ByVal bcc_list As String, _
    ByVal rr As Boolean) As String

    Dim oOlApp As Object    ' Outlook.Application
    Dim oOlMItem As Object  ' Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oWdDoc As Object    ' Word.Document

    Err.Clear

    Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    ' Range can be copied directly as given as Range via function call
    mail_content.Copy

    ' On Error Resume Next   ' activate it after debugging
    With oOlMItem
        .To = send_to
        .CC = cc_list
        .BCC = bcc_list
        .Subject = mail_subject
        .ReadReceiptRequested = rr ' can be used directly if given as boolean
        .BodyFormat = 3 ' 3=RichTextFormat

        Set oWdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor

        ' by this you paste below your signature
        ' oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Paste

        ' by these alternatives you paste before your signature
        oWdDoc.Range(oWdDoc.Content.Start, oWdDoc.Content.Start).Paste
        oWdDoc.Bookmarks("\StartOfDoc").Range.Paste

        .Display ' change to .Send after debugging
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        send_mail_rich_text = "error"
    ElseIf oOlMItem.Sent = True Then
        send_mail_rich_text = "sent"
    Else
        send_mail_rich_text = "no error, but not sent"
    End If
End Function
```

As `ReadReceiptRequested` is expected as boolean, I changed it within the function call. Be aware to change your calls to this function accordingly. I tested it with this:

```
Private Sub TestSendmailFunction()
    Debug.Print send_mail_rich_text("to@test.com", "Test", ActiveSheet.Range("B2:C3"), _
        "cc@test.com", "bcc@test.com", False)
End Sub
```

It is not necessary to switch to another sheet and later back to the previous one as you give "mail_content" as range. A range can be copied directly also from non-active sheets.

You should use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of every VBA module to prevent errors like "send_mail_rich_text" vs. "save_mail_rich_text" or unknown objects like oWdRng.

You can combine commands if you don't need the object again: Instead of `Set oWdRng = ...` and `oWdRng.Paste` you can use the whole part: `....Paste`.

If you can add a reference to "Microsoft Excel x.x Object Library" and "Microsoft Word x.x Object Library" then you can exchange `Object` by e. g. `Outlook.Mailitem` to provide more debugging features by "early binding". Then also the predefinded constants as `olFormatRichText` (from internal ENUM OlBodyFormat) are known and can be used directly.